# How to use the variable inside another variable

Tags: batch-file

How would I do to use the variable **%number%** in this case?

```
Set Test=%strToMeasure:~-%Number%%
```

Whenever I use a variable the result comes out like this:

**No variable only the number:**

```
Set Test=%strToMeasure:~-3%
```

[image]

**With variable:**

```
Set Test=%strToMeasure:~-%Number%%
```

[image]

**Full Code**

```
@echo off

Set "strToMeasure=This is a string"
call :strLen strToMeasure strlen
echo.String is %strlen% characters long
Set /A number = %strlen% - 13

Set Test=%strToMeasure:~-%Number%%

Echo %strToMeasure%
Echo %Test%

pause


exit /b

:strLen
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:strLen_Loop
  if not "!%1:~%len%!"=="" set /A len+=1 & goto :strLen_Loop
(endlocal & set %2=%len%)
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options in order to correctly execute this line:

```
Set Test=%strToMeasure:~-%Number%%
```

1- Doubling the percent signs for the second expansion and using `call` command:

```
Call Set Test=%%strToMeasure:~-%Number%%%
```

2- Using Delayed Expansion and enclosing the second expansion in exclamation marks:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

. . .

Set Test=!strToMeasure:~-%Number%!
```

The second method is the usual way to solve this problem and it run faster than the former. You may review further details of this behavior at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).